# Is there a way to use Lua on BREW 3.0 platform?

Tags: mobile, lua, brew-framework

It looks like [BREW](http://brew.qualcomm.com/brew/) 4.0 will have Lua included. But is it possible to use Lua on older BREW 3.0 (or even BREW 2.0)?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, but you will have to link lua interpreter source code to your application source code and wrap BREW API functions in order to use them from lua scripts.

Check out [LuaBREW](http://luaforge.net/projects/luabrew) project as an example of approach I briefly explained above.

Answer (score 2):

We did this. I ported Lua to BREW turning it into a uiOne actor. Worked well, took about 3 days to get it working properly, mostly on the actor side. As far as I recall there was nothing in there that wouldn't have worked on BREW 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

We don't wait BREW 4.0. We are writing our LuaBREW implementation right now.